# Can iterate be written with a fold?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, iteration, lazy-evaluation, fold

### Foreword

I was experimenting with the idea of repeatedly applying a function `f` to a given argument `z`, over and over, thus getting an infinite list.

Basically I want the list `[z, f z, f (f z), f (f (f z)), ...]`, which I could feed to `take n`, `takeWhile whatever`, or something else.

Initially I thought that since the list I'm gonna deal with is infinite (I was thinking of `repeat f`), I should use `foldr`, but in reality that's not possible, because when `foldr`ing an infinite list the accumulator is usually set to `undefined` because unused, so in something like `foldr (\f (x:xs) -> f x:x:xs) undefined (repeat f)` I wouldn't have were to put `z`.

### The question

So I started writing this question, and, thanks to the automatic suggestions that pop up, I discovered that [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#iterate) exists already, and its implementation is,

```hs
{-# NOINLINE [1] iterate #-}
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x =  x : iterate f (f x)
```

so my question changed: is it possible to write `iterate` as a fold? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: A fold requires a list to operate on. `iterate` does not get any list in its inputs, so I'd say it's impossible. Using `repeat f` to provide a list to fold on is cheating in my eye (feel free to disagree, of course!). On the other hand, one could use `unfoldr` to code `iterate`.

Comment: One language with only list constructors and folds, without general recursion, is the simply-typed lambda calculus with fold, which is stronly normalizing ("terminating"). (This calculus is a simple variant of [PCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Computable_Functions).) If you could construct an infinite list in such a language, you could not terminate by folding it. Another way to see this is that this calculus has a simple denotational semantics where lists are finite, so iterate cannot be expressed.

Answer (score 12):

No, or at least not in any idiomatic way. But that's because `foldr` is the wrong tool for the job. `foldr` is a fold, or *catamorphism*. That's a fancy mathematical way of saying it takes aggregate data (in this case, a list) and produces a single result (a scalar, such as a number). This is why operations like `sum` are straightforward to write in terms of `foldr`, because `sum` fundamentally takes aggregate data and produces a singular result.

What you want is an *anamorphism*, or a way to take a single point of data (`z` in your example) and produce aggregate data from that. In Haskell, this is appropriately named [`unfoldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr).

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

`unfoldr` starts with ab initial value `b` and calls the function it's given. Each time it calls the function, if it produces a `Just (a, b')`, then we use `a` as the first element of the list and continue with `b'` as the state value. If the function returns `Nothing`, then we stop iterating.

In your case, you want to produce an infinite list, so we'll always return a `Just` value. You can write `iterate` in terms of `unfoldr` as follows.

```
import Data.List(unfoldr)

iterate' :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate' f = unfoldr (\z -> Just (z, f z))
```

Answer (score 4):

To me using `repeat f` as you suggest amounts to "cheating", since you hide an infinite recursion in that infinite list. The proper way is to use anamorphisms (`unfoldr`) as Silvio Mayolo already explained.

That being said, if that's allowed then we can implement `iterate` as a fold. Here's an example where we obtain `iterate ('b':) "X"` in GHCi:

```
> take 9 $ foldr (\ x xs k -> k : xs (x k) ) (\_ -> []) (repeat ('b':)) "X"
["X","bX","bbX","bbbX","bbbbX","bbbbbX","bbbbbbX","bbbbbbbX","bbbbbbbbX"]
```

This uses the (in-)famous trick "calling `foldr` with four arguments". The idea is to make it so that the fold returns a function, which we eventually feed with the initial value of `iterate`, namely `"X"`. This allows us to modify that fourth argument in each "recursive call": when we write `xs (x k)` we are essentially calling `xs`, the function computed by the fold on the rest of the list, with `x k` which is actually `'b':k`, effectively passing the next value in the iteration list.

---

One of the reasons I don't like this approach is that we don't even need `repeat f`. Indeed, `repeat ()` would be enough to drive the fold.

```
> take 9 $ foldr (\ _ xs k -> k : xs ('b':k) ) (\_ -> []) (repeat ()) "X"
["X","bX","bbX","bbbX","bbbbX","bbbbbX","bbbbbbX","bbbbbbbX","bbbbbbbbX"]
```

Even worse: if we have access to `repeat ()` we can write out a fixed point combinator (for function types):

```
> myFix f = foldr (\ _ xs -> f . xs) id (repeat ()) id
> :t myFix
myFix :: ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Here's the factorial computed using the fixed point operator:

```
> myFix (\g n -> if n==0 then 1 else n * g (n-1)) 5
120
```

Comment: On the one hand, mindblowing, but on the other hand, if I understand correctly, when pulling out `n` elements via `take n`, the function `('b':)` is applied `n*(n+1)/2` times, i.e. `O(n²)`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Enlico I think it's only O(n). The applications are shared, so I believe it's similar to `let x = "X"; x1 = 'b':x ; x2 = 'b':x1 ; ... in [ x,x1,x2,x3,...]`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I made a mistake. If `f` is the lambda applied to `()`, then the `foldr lambda undefined (repeat ()) "X"` is `(f $ f $ f $ ...) "X" == "X":(f $ f $ f $ ...) ('b':"X") == "X":('b':"X"):(f $ f $ f $ ...) ('b':'b':"X")`, but the rightmost `'b':"X"` is actually the already computed value at the previous step.